# Yii: parametrized call of javascript - problems with quotes

Tags: javascript, php, yii, components, quote

I am using Yii Version 1.1.15.

In a View I use ajaxlink and it works like a charme:

```
<?=
  CHtml::ajaxLink(
     '[Help]',
     $this->createUrl('genearal/help'), 
     array(
        'onclick' => '$("#help").dialog("open"); return false;',
        'update' => '#help'), 
     array('id' => 'showHelp')
  );
?>
<div id="help"></div>
```

Since I have a lot of ajaxlink-calls, I want to write a function in the components-folder which I can call with:
    MyComponents::help("Help", "general/help", "help", "showHelp");

```
class MyComponents {
    public static function help($headline, $controller_and_action, $divname, $idname) {
              CHtml::ajaxLink(
                 '[$headline]',
                 $this->createUrl('$controller_and_action'), 
                 array(
                   'onclick' => '$("$divname").dialog("open"); return false;',
                   'update' => '$divname'), 
                 array('id' => '$idname')
              );
    }
}
```

**Problem:** If I call this in the browser, I only get an empty page.

Do I have to extend MyComponents with a parentclass? Which? (I don't think so: I tested echo CHtml::encode("test") without problems.

Maybe something wrong with my quotes?

I was googeling for hours and gave up. Hope it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was very simple.
I didn't get an erromessage and therefore thought that something was going wrong with javascript.

In my controller I am not in an object-context - so $this->createUrl(...) is not possible. The solution:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl(...)
```

... and it works like a charme ;-)